# Thread.Sleep replacement in .NET for Windows Store

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store, windows-store-apps

[Thread.Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) doesn't seem to be supported in .NET for Windows Store apps.

For example, this

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

will compile when targeting any .NET Framework (2.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5), but not when targeting .NET for Windows Store apps (or in a portable class library which targets both 4.5 and store).

System.Threading.Thread is still there, it just doesn't have the Sleep method.

I need to delay something for a few seconds in my app, is there a suitable replacement?

EDIT why the delay is needed: My app is a game and the delay is to make it look like the computer opponent is "thinking" about his next move. The method is already called asynchronously (main thread isn't blocked), I just want to slow the response time down.

Comment: Considering Windows Store apps are not supposed to be able to freeze the UI (everything is supposed to be async) it makes sense that it is not supported.

Comment: Do you have Events or the `Monitor` class? You can use the `Wait` method with a timeout to simulate a sleep.

Comment: is this for Apptivate.ms ? :3

Comment: Yay for banishing `Thread.Sleep` to the dustbin of bad tech.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Windows Store apps embrace asynchrony - and an "asynchronous pause" is provided by [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay.aspx). So within an asynchronous method, you'd write:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

... or whatever delay you want. The asynchronous method will continue 30 seconds later, but the thread will *not* be blocked, just as for all `await` expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately, Task.Delay doesn't seem to be supported when targeting .NET 4.5 + store + WP7 in a portable class library.. I guess I'll have move this into the platform specific classes.

Comment: @Max: No, because it didn't exist before .NET 4.5. IIRC, WP7 itself doesn't have any TPL support. (I could be wrong...)

Comment: You can tack on `.RunSynchronously()` if needed.

Comment: You can also use Microsoft.Bcl.Async's TaskEx.Delay, you cab grab the package using NuGet.

Comment: If it's awaitable, why didn't they call it `DelayAsync()`?

Comment: @Jay: It's felt that methods which are *clearly* about asynchrony are okay without the suffix, e.g. `Task.Run`.

Comment: @RAM: Well then it's not a Windows Store app to start with, so we're in a completely different context - I'd suggest that in that case you ask a new question with more details.

Comment: @JonSkeet, my platform is **C# .NET 3.5 WPF**. i found some ways but i don't know what is the best and short way. do you know any good answer in stackoverflow for it? I can write a new question but i like know your suggestions. do you suggest new question in stackoverflow? thanks...

Comment: @RAM: Well `Thread.Sleep` *is* supported in .NET 3.5, so the question doesn't apply. No doubt you have *a* question, but it doesn't sound like it's the same as this one. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints then ask a new question.

Comment: @RAM: I'm not sure how I was meant to guess that from your comments. There are plenty of similar questions on SO already about WPF and animation.

Answer (score 46):

Hate to state the obvious but in case anybody wanted a single line `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(3000).Wait()`

Answer (score 20):

I just had the same problem and found another interesting solution that I wanted to share with you. If you really want to block the thread I would do it like this (thanks @Brannon for the "slim" hint):

```
// `waitHandle.Set` is never called, so we wait always until the timeout occurs
using (var waitHandle = new ManualResetEventSlim(initialState: false))
{
    waitHandle.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer for portable coding.

Comment: Use the "slim" version of this.

Answer (score 11):

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  this.WaitForFiveSeconds();
}

private async void WaitForFiveSeconds()
{
  await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
  // do something after 5 seconds!
}
```

Answer (score -7):

There is almost NO reason (except for testing purposes) to EVER use `Thread.Sleep()`.

IF (and only if) you have a very good reason to send a thread to sleep, you might want to check `Task.Delay()` , which you can await to "wait" for a specified time. Though it's never a good idea to have a thread sitting around and do nothing. Bad practise ...

Comment: I disagree. If the thread is a background thread and the sleep is short then it is more efficient to have it sleep for a few milliseconds than using a timer.

Comment: and sometimes you're told to do it despite advising said authority figure of the consequences ;)