# The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

When I put this code `Thread.Sleep(2000);` it gives me the error:

> The name 'Thread' does not exist in the current context`.

I already included the namespace `using System.Threading;`. See [`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()` on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Can we see your code as well? Are you sure you don't have another `Thread` as a variable or something?

Comment: Is this a windows store project?

Comment: yes it is. i'm adding a delay just to increase splash screen displaying

Comment: i mean it is windows phone project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume this is a Portable Class Library or Windows Store/Phone project targeting Windows Runtime which does not have such a construct.

---

An alternative and recommended way would be to use:

`await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));`

or for a blocking call in case you are not in an async context:

`Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)).Wait();`

Similar issue is also brought out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641223/thread-sleep-replacement-in-net-for-windows-store).

Answer (score 13):

Try using the full Name Space in your code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```